# use a pointer in operation with non pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm quite new to C++ and I don't understand very well the pointers yet.

this is ok, I have 2 non pointer object:

```
Vec2D A(0, 0), B(10, 10);
Vec2D C = A-B;
```

but if one is a pointer?

```
Vec2D::minus(Vec2D B) {
    Vec2D that = Vec2D(this->x(), this->y());
    return that-B;
}
```

So the question: how can I use the pointer `this` with `-` operation with B?

And also, I don't understand how many object are constructed in my methods and how can I optimize memory consumption passing some reference..

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I also would have expected a better question given that you asked >100 questions.

Comment: Hey, whoa. Ask one (specific) question at a time. I'm counting 3 since your last edit ("What's 'this'?", "How am I constructing objects?" and "How do I use references?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly.. "this is a pointer, how can I operate on it and other pointers using methods that require a non-pointer?"

You use the dereference operator `*`
Example:

```
Vec2D that = *this;
```

To answer your second question:

- an object is created to pass it as a parameter of `minus`
- an object is created by `Vec2D(this->x(), this->y())` (but will be probably erased away as a temp by a good optimizing compiler)
- an object is created by you on the stack (`that`)
- depending on how you implemented them, and on how good your compiler is, you may create another object in your copy constructor/operator=
- an object (or more) may be created by your operator- in `that-B`
- an object is created to be returned (only one, not two, as return value optimization is done by all compliers AFAIK)

How can you optimize it? Use references...

```
Vec2D Vec2D::minus(const Vec2D& B) {
   return that-*this;
}
```

And implement operator- on Vec2D to use refereces too...
In general, pass parameters as (const) references.

Obviously, you cannot do the same for the return value (try, the compiler will complain..); there are techniques for these as well (especially in CG/games, with vectors, I have seen object pools used a lot; for those returning a reference/pointer is actually possible, but it is rather advanced stuff)

Answer (score 0):

The "this" pointer is an auto-generated pointer to the object that contains the method being called.

If you call `A.minus(B)`, the "this" pointer points to A.